# How to generate a heatmap based on a json file

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I have a json file containing 200000 point coordinates in geojson format and I want to generate a heat map of these coordinates. I have two ideas to do that but I have problems with both ideas:

1. use google map-->heatmap layer. I plan to write a html file as shown on 
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap
   , however, I dont know how to put the coordinates of json file into the batch of google.maps.LatLng(), any idea?
2. use google Fusion Table. However, it seems that a delimited text file(.csv, .tsv, or .txt), and Keyhole Markup Language file(.kml) are necessary, is that right?

I don't know whether there are some other good ways to generate a heat map. Any good idea?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that geoJson is a good choice to transport such an amount of data(I wouldn't even use it  for 2000 items).

Let's take a look at a single LatLng, (lets assume 5 decimals):
to simply transport the needed data via JSON you would need e.g.:

```
//17 bytes, about 3.5 MB for 200000 points
[9.12345,5.43219]
```

in geoJson:

```
//95 bytes, about 18 MB for 200000 items
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type": "Point","coordinates":[5.43219,9.12345]},"properties":{}}
```

I guess I don't have to say anything....

**The basic issue with #1:** (I don't think it's recommendable for 200000 points, no matter which format you choose):
As you can't transport a `google.maps.LatLng` via JSON, you'll need to pre-process the JSON to create an array with LatLngs(will  take some time for 200000 points)

**I think #2 is the only option you should think about**.

You may set up a script, macro, etc. which parses the geoJson when it's static and upload it to a FusionTable.

When the data are not static you may use a serverside script which uploads/updates the data automatically.

KML isn't required for points, you may simply use a CSV(lat and lng may be stored in a single field, delimited by a comma) or in separate fields.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why you should go for option#1.

***a)*** Serializing the GeoJSON data points to GoogleMap-compatible format latlng is relatively easier than option #2. You can even load GeoJSON data, parse it to GoogleMap coordinate, and draw on the map without any need to convert the file type.

***b)*** If you choose option 2, you definitely need to write a script which converts GeoJSON file to a comma-delimited (or whatever symbol) text file. When you have a new GeoJSON data, you will need to convert it again. This doesn't save your time.

***So let's say you choose option #1***

You can just add a script tag which refers to your GeoJSON data file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>
```

Then parse it into a JSON format with your JavaScript code like this:

```
var geoData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Then you'll need to parse these geoJSON data into an array of lat-lng coordinates:

```
var coords = geoData.map(function mapToLatLng(c){
    return new google.maps.LatLng(c.geometry.coordinates[0], c.geometry.coordinates[1])
});
```

With this code above, you should get `coords` which carries all Google Map latitude-longitude coordinates ready for rendering into a heatmap.

To render those points, you may try:

```
heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: new google.maps.MVCArray(coords)
});
heatmap.setMap(map);
```

Comment: BTW, the example above refers to `data.json` as your GeoJSON input data file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am quite new to this kind of things, I wanna ask: in <script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>, should the "data.json" in src="data.json" be the path to the file? Or I just save the file under the same folder as I save the html script

Comment: I just use the codes on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap but change the TaxiData as you do in your answer, but it shows nothing....Maybe something wrong with my input file?